# Overflow Menu icon in Custom Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-optionsmenu

I am using a custom toolbar which has a menu icon. Now on clicking this menu icon i want to show the options menu. How can this be done.

I tried adding a onclicklistener to this menu icon

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    if(v.getId() == R.id.toolbarMenuIcon){
        openOptionsMenu();
    }

}
```

This didnt work. Then i added these lines

```
setSupportActionBar(mBinding.customSelectToolbar.selectionModeToolbar);
```

in my activitys oncreate() . Also did override

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.selection_mode_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

With this i can see the overflow menu when i click the icon. But the problem is that, it adds the default menu icon also to the tool bar and thus my tool bar has two menu now. How can i have only my custom toolbar icon open the options menu

Comment: `it adds the default menu icon`?...do you add a custom menu icon in your toolbar?

Comment: yes i have an icon toolbarMenuIcon in my toolbar layout. I want to show the options menu on clicking this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to customize the default overflow menu icon..

Use [setOverflowIcon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setOverflowIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method of your toolbar.

like:

```
 toolbar.setOverflowIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_icon));
```

Comment: i have all other icons on toolbar also customised. So is it not possible to have a button that act as options menu icon on click

Comment: sounds like you want something like [This](http://keepsafe.github.io/2014/11/19/building-a-custom-overflow-menu.html)

Comment: Also your question is not clear...if you set the custom icon as your overflow menu....it will open the options as well !..you need to override the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`...to  to define the onClick behaviour of your `MenuItem`..

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I dont want to show a popup menu. "if you set the custom icon as your overflow menu....it will open the options as well !." This is not happening if i just call openOptionsMenu without setting setSupportActionBar(mytoolbar) . The oncreateOptionsmenu is never getting triggered in that case

Comment: the 'oncreateOptionsmenu` is the method of `Actionbar` by calling `setSupportActionBar(mytoolbar)` we enable the toolbar as actionbar..without it it will never work, also i don't figure out what is the problem by `setSupportActionBar(mytoolbar)`? also this is out of topic in your question..u better repost ur question again..!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using theme

```
<style name="OverFlow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_overflow</item>
    <item name="android:tint">...</item>
    <item name="android:width">..dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">..dp</item>

</style>

<style name="OnArrival.toolbarTheme" parent="Theme.OnArrival.Light">

    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>
```